# Как упростить код созданием своей библиотеки? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

[Имею свою конструкцию](https://github.com/andrwgldmn/SimpleCalcPython/blob/master/calc.py)
Нужно с

```
value = input(" Вы хотите продолжить? \n \n Если да, введите 1. \n \n Если нет, введите 0. \n \n " )
if (value == 0):
   print ('----------------------------')
   print (" Спасибо за использование!")
   print ('----------------------------')
   sys.exit()
elif (value == 1):
   start = 1
```

сделать свой модуль чтобы просто заменить этот блок. Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вам нужно просто сократить данный код то можно таким способом

```
if int(input(" Вы хотите продолжить? \n  Если да, введите 1. \n  Если нет, введите 0. \n")):
    start = 1
else:
    print('-' * 28 + '\n Спасибо за использование!\n' + '-' * 28)
```